# Learning Python. What does P do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning Python. The book I'm studying has the code below. I understand the general meaning and the end result but I don't understand where `P` came from and what it does. Could you explain it to me, please?

```
parts = ['43', '44', '45\n']
numbers = [int(P) for P in parts]
```

Comment: The `P` is an internal variable in what is called a "list comprehension".   The line
`numbers = [int(P) for P in parts]` is just a compressed for-loop

Answer (score 0):

In your case P is just a variable where you use to get each individual part(P) from list of parts.